Ansible - How to create an archive with extra options?
I'm trying to use the archive module in Ansible but have extra flags I need to use, specifically for tar.
I've used the unarchive module with the parameter extra_opts but I don't see anything like that for the archive module.
I'm trying to add a file to an existing archive with the -u / --update flag. Can this be achieved using this module? Additionally I'm also needing to use the --owner flag.
I'm currently using a shell command task to do this but I get annoying warning messages about using the unarchive command and Ansible removed the ability to disable warning messages apparently... I'd prefer to do this in the Ansible orthodox way, if possible.


... but I don't see anything like that for the archive module.

Right, that is the case. This is mostly because many Ansible modules are just wrapper for underlying functionality, of in example the operation system. In case of the archive module for certain other tools like tar, gtar, zip, etc. Therefore not all options and corner cases are implemented.

I'm currently using a shell command task

And which is the option for Use Cases where no modules or specific functionality exists.

I'd prefer to do this in the Ansible orthodox way, if possible.

That would be enhancing the existing module code plugins/modules/archive.py or implementing a Custom Module.
